# JtR requires OpenSSL and OpenSSL-devel being installed

Tags: macos, openssl

I'm on macos high sierra and trying to build `john the ripper bleeding-jumbo`.
Being in the `src` folder and executing `./configure && make` I get the following message

```
configure: error: JtR requires OpenSSL and OpenSSL-devel being installed. Install if not installed.
Try using --disable-pkg-config and possibly helping configure find oSSL by providing hints in CFLAGS and LDFLAGS
See `config.log' for more details
```

The command `which openssl` delivers

```
/usr/bin/openssl
```

`openssl` is installed but it seems it cannot find it, also the development package seems to be missing. How do I get around this?
I couldn't find any working hints on how to install openssl-devel either. There is some information on how to install `openssl` via brew but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution to get around that problem.

From previous attempts `brew link openssl --force` told me

```
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

So after following the advice in the [mailing list](https://marc.info/?l=john-dev&m=140181056626215&w=2) I executed

```
export CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
```

after that I tried to configure again

```
./configure --disable-pkg-config
```

That got me behind the ssl problems

Answer (score 0):

For **Centos** users:

`libssl` and `libssl-dev` are for ubuntu users.

install `OpenSSL` and `OpenSSL-devel` libraries.

```
yum install -y openssl openssl-devel
```

then make a fresh clean install of **JTR**.

```
yum -y install wget gpgme
yum -y group install "Development Tools"
cd ~
wget http://www.openwall.com/john/k/john-1.9.0-jumbo-1.tar.xz
wget http://www.openwall.com/john/k/john-1.9.0-jumbo-1.tar.xz.sign
wget http://www.openwall.com/signatures/openwall-signatures.asc
gpg --import openwall-signatures.asc
gpg --verify john-1.9.0-jumbo-1.tar.xz.sign
tar xvfJ john-1.9.0-jumbo-1.tar.xz
cd john-1.9.0-jumbo-1/src
./configure && make
```

And finally test **JTR**:

```
cd ../run/
./john --test
```